# g:message with arguments inside Javascript / jQuery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I had an issue where String arguments were being truncated to the first character in our g:message tags (longs/integers seemed to be fine).

Ultimately, I figured out we were not calling g:message syntactically correct from within Javascript so some minor tweaks fixed the issue. Problem is - I don't understand why the former doesn't work.

Can anyone describe what was happening here?

```
jQuery("#myId").html("<g:message code='domain.message.path' args="${command?.foo?.name}"/>"); //incorrect, only displays first character of message

jQuery("#myId").html("${g.message(code: 'domain.message.path', args: [command?.foo?.name])}"); //correct, displays full string
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're rendering this as part of a .gsp page?  Here's the thing.  In the first one, you're nesting quotes, essentially leaving the ${} section out of the string.  Even Stackoverflow can tell; note how that part is a different color:

```
jQuery("#myId").html("<g:message code='domain.message.path' args="${command?.foo?.name}"/>");
```

See how the quote at the end of html( is ended by the quote before ${, leaving the ${command?.foo?.name} block outside the string?  If command.foo.name was the string "bob", then when this rendered, you'd get:

```
jQuery("#myId").html("<g:message code='domain.message.path' args="bob"/>");
```

You might think this looks right, but javascript will handle this poorly.

If you used single quotes for the internal string, like you do with 'domain.message.path', it should work fine:

```
jQuery("#myId").html("<g:message code='domain.message.path' args='${command?.foo?.name}'/>");
```